# SetWeek negative deprecated

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdatecomponents

I was creating a DateRange like this one in my App:

```
NSDateComponents *myDateComponentsStart = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[myDateComponentsStart setWeek:-2];

NSDateComponents *myDateComponentsEnd = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[myDateComponentsEnd setWeek:+2];

DateRange *myDateRage = [[DateRange dateRangeForToday] dateRangeByAddingStartDateComponents:myDateComponentsStart endDateComponents:myDateComponentsEnd];
```

It means a range between 2 weeks in the past and 2 weeks in the future.

But it seems setWeek is deprecated yet for iOS 8. It propose changing it by setWeekOfMonth or setWeekOfYear.

Since I don't care any change of month or year. What should I use now? I just want a period of 4 week with today in the middle, no worries about months or years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost certainly want `weekOfYear`. Although `weekOfYear` and `weekOfMonth` seem to produce the same result when you also specify `NSCalendarWrapComponents`, `weekOfYear` is semantically closer to your intent.

Answer (score 1):

From my personal experience 'weekOfMonth' seems to give the same results that 'week' used to be.

weekOfYear seems to never work as I want it to.